# C# code has issues with RamDisk path length

Tags: c#, ramdisk

I've copied a file over to a RAM Disk, but I get an error message that doesn't make sense as the path is actually shorter than on the physical disk and is certainly less than 260 characters. Any suggestions how to get around this issue. Changing the code is not an option.

I'm using ImDisk to create the RAM Disk. My RamDisk is defined as `Z:`

```
The file resolves to a path that is too long. The maximum length is 260 characters. [ File name = Z:\zz\xx\yy\xyz.sdf ]
```

here is what I have tried:

- Manually shortening the path - i.e. havingthe shortest parent - i.e.
  just use the drive.
- I've been looking at using mklink to build out    some links using \J
  \D options. But still doesn't work - using both:
  Physical -> RamDisk and RamDisk -> RamDisk.
- Substr, for mapping the RamDisk path to a letter. This makes no difference.
- \?\, I tried this - but I get issues with the program as I think it
  checks for not standard paths and I cannot modify the source code.
- I've tried a combination of using \?\ with mklink, so I create a
  link which makes to \?\z:

Comment: is z: really the letter assigned by windows or did you mapped it as a network address?

Comment: @heringer it is the RamDisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I may have this working, I did it using a windows share. I went to the folder on the RAMDisk and shared this folder by right clicking. These so far seems to work and I can run my C# compiled code.